# are thought to work in... - already working or expected to work?

Tags: comprehension

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/ruble-weakens-central-asian-migrants-head-back-home-055736647.html):

> The Tajik government has vowed to create 200,000 jobs this year but experts say it will be far too little to meet the demands of returning migrants. Between 700,000 and one million Tajiks **are thought to work** in Russia.

I'm not sure how exactly I should interpret that part. I think what it really says is that it is assumed or believed that there are between 700,000 and one million Tajik workers right now working in Russia. But why not say *are thought to be working in Russia* instead since they are in Russia and they are WORKING there? Because the way it's written sounds more like the author is trying to say that they are expected to go to Russia to work in the future rather than they are currently in Russia working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think you're so much "missing" something as *inventing* an interpretation/implication that doesn't match native speaker usage or understanding. If I choose to say *"25,000 Jews **are living** in Poland"* rather than the simpler (and more "natural") *"25,000 Jews **live** in Poland"*, this might carry a *very slight* implication that those Jews didn't always live there and/or might not remain there indefinitely, but I can't see any reason to think the construction could in any way imply they're not there *now*.

Comment: Compare: "For decades, high-cholesterol foods *were thought to increase* blood cholesterol; but the science did not support that view."  It was believed that such foods increased blood cholesterol. Doctors believed that such foods increased blood cholesterol.

Comment: "Are thought to work" and "are thought to be working" mean much the same thing. What is the difference between "I live on planet Earth" and "I am living on planet Earth"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers that should be an answer, because it's exactly right.  Post it, why don't you, so we can vote it up.

Comment: @Codeswitcher: I assume there's some *reason* why OP thinks Present Continuous might be more appropriate (or why Simple Present might imply *in the future* rather than *currently*). But I don't know what that reason might be, so I'd rather see if someone else can explain what's going on here. Simply saying "there's no such implication" seems a bit of a cop-out to me.

Comment: *...unless...* (this has just occurred to me) OP is thinking of what the cited text would mean if we remove the word ***thought***. In which case we'd have *"Between 700,000 and one million Tajiks **are to work** in Russia"*, which obviously ***is*** a reference to a future time when they ***will*** work there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, as much as I appreciate high standards, I think you're working too hard at this. :) You have answered the question asked.  You're not required to debug the asker's thought process; it's nice when an answerer pulls that off, but it's lagniappe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OP's context,...

> 1a: *Many Tajiks are thought to work in Russia*
>     1b: *Many Tajiks are thought to be working in Russia*

...are largely equivalent. With the specific verb *to work*, it doesn't make much difference whether we use it in the [infinitive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/infinitive) (1a, ***work***), or as a [present participle](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm) preceded by *to be* in the infinitive (1b, ***working***). Note that we can remove the *thought* part (or relocate it to the front, to preserve the exact meaning)...

> 2: *It is believed that...*
>    2a: *...many Tajiks work in Russia*
>     2b: *...many Tajiks are working in Russia*

---

Also note that there *can* be differences in acceptability/meaning if we consider a different verb...

> 3a: *Many Tajiks support Russia*
>     3b: *Many Tajiks are supporting Russia*
>
> 4a: *Many Tajiks speak Russian*
>     4b: ??*Many Tajiks are speaking Russian* (idiomatically unlikely in almost all contexts)

...where 3a carries more of the implication that many Tajiks *always have and always will* support Russia, and 3b tends to imply they're specifically supporting Russia *in the current context*. And 4b would not normally be acceptable to native speakers (though it's a relatively common "error" in [Indian English](http://blogs.intoday.in/businesstoday/Indianism-of-the-Week-37---continuous-tense-62749.html)).

---

Per my earlier comment, it's possible the reason OP (mistakenly) thinks there might be some distinction between 1a/1b relating to a *future* situation may based on...

> 5a: *Many Tajiks are to work in Russia*
>     5b: ??*Many Tajiks are to be working in Russia* (idiomatically unlikely)

...where 5a is equivalent to *Many Tajiks **will** work in Russia*, but with the additional implication that this future situation is in some sense "planned".